# Integration by substitution versus integration by parts

Tags: calculus

So I've been going back over integration. In a section that concentrated mostly on integration by parts, I came across this question.

$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^3}{\sqrt{3+x^2}} dx$ and it was done by substitution (with $u = 3+x^2$).

My question is why was this method used rather than integration by parts, where $u = x^3$ and $dv = (3+x^2)^{-1/2}$?

Thank you

Comment: The integration by parts as you suggest would be difficult. $dv$ would integrate as an hyperbolic function $\text{arsinh}$, and the factor $x^3$ would yield $x^2$,leading to an even more difficult problem. Anyway, using $u=x^2$ and $dv=x/\sqrt{x^2+3}$ is doable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because with the substitution
$$
u=3+x^2 \quad \rightarrow \quad du=2xdx
$$

we find the simple integral:

$$
\int_0^1\frac{u-3}{2\sqrt{u}}du
$$

But with 
$$
u=x^3 \quad \rightarrow \quad du=3x^2dx
$$
and
$$
dv=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3+x^2}} \quad \rightarrow \quad v=\sinh^{-1}\left( \frac{x}{\sqrt{3}}\right)
$$

we find a result that is more difficult to integrate (can you see it?).

Comment: Great, thank you very much, I get it now

Comment: great thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

settinbg $$u=x^2$$ then we have $$du=2xdx$$ and our integral is
$$\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^1\frac{udu}{\sqrt{u+3}}$$ and now we Substitute
$$s=u+3$$ and we get $$ds=du$$ and we have $$\frac{1}{2}\int_{3}^4\sqrt{s}-\frac{3}{\sqrt{s}}ds$$
can you finish?

Answer (score 1):

$$\int\frac{x^3\,dx}{\sqrt{x^2+3}}=\int\frac{x(x^2+3)-3x}{\sqrt{x^2+3}}dx=\int x\sqrt{x^2+3}\,dx-3\int\frac x{\sqrt{x^2+3}}dx\\
=\frac13(x^2+3)^{3/2}-3\sqrt{x^2+3}.$$

Hence integration by decomposition also works. :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, if we use integration by parts, you do the following (continuing your selected u's):

$u = x^3$

$v = (3+x^2)^{-1/2}$

$u'=3x^2$

$\int vdx$ = $\frac{(3+x^2)^{1/2}}{x}$

Then, putting everything into the integration by part format, (first without the limits)

$\int {x^3}{(3+x^2)^{-1/2}} dx$ = $x^3$(${3x(3+x^2)^{1/2}}$) - $3x^2$$\int \frac{(3+x^2)^{1/2}}{x}dx$

= $3x^4$${(3+x^2)^{1/2}}$ - $\frac{(3+x^2)^{3/2}}{x} + C$

Afterwards, you'd need to simplify the equation even more by finding same denominator, etc.

However, if we use integration by substitution, then you'd do the following:

$u = 3+x^2$

$du = 2xdx$

And re-write the original integral as the following:

$\int{x^3}(3+x^2)^{-1/2}dx$

So..
I gave up on the TeX formulating and had to use paint, so 
[here are the next steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5ovu.png).

In this case, substitution is less 'exhausting' in terms of steps and speed. 
Integration by part is commonly used for very simple integrals.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to tackle the integral by integration by parts.
\begin{aligned}
& \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^{3}}{\sqrt{3+x^{2}}} d x \\
=& \int_{0}^{1} x^{2} d (\sqrt{3+x^{2}}) \\
=&\left[x^{2} \sqrt{3+x^{2}}\right]_{0}^{1}-\int_{0}^{1} \sqrt{3+x^{2}} d\left(x^{2}\right) \\
=&2-\left[\frac{\left(3+x^{2}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}+1}}{\frac{1}{2}+1}\right]_{0}^{1} \\
=& 2-\frac{2}{3}(8-3 \sqrt{3}) \\
=& \frac{1}{3}(6 \sqrt{3}-10)
\end{aligned}