# How do I solve $ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{3+x^2}}dx$?

Tags: integration, analysis

I had to solve this integral:

$$
\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{3+x^2}}\mathrm{d}x
$$
by the substitution $x=\sqrt{3}t$ the indefinite integral can be written as:
$$
\int \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{3+x^2}}\;\mathrm{d}x = \int \frac{3t^2}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}\; \mathrm{d}t
$$
at this stage I performed the substitution $\displaystyle t=\frac{e^u-e^{-u}}{2}$, but the computations are definitely too tough for being a high school exercise.
I'd like to know if there's a simpler method, by substitution, that allows to solve it.

Comment: $$1-\frac{3}{2} \tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$$

Comment: Try an [Euler substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution); in fact, you can use the same one employed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4650777/170231)

Comment: Sorry, I retracted my proposition of [duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2536576) because the numerator there is $x^3,$ not $x^2.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Integration by parts & Hyperbolic substution**
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^1 \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{3+x^2}} d x & =\int_0^1 x d\left(\sqrt{3+x^2}\right) \\
& =\left[x \sqrt{3+x^2}\right]_0^1-\int_0^1 \sqrt{3+x^2} d x \\
&=2-\frac{1}{2} \left[ x \sqrt{x^2+3}+3 \sinh ^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{3}}\right)\right]_0^1 \\
& =1-\frac{3}{2} \sinh ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 2):

**HINT (EDIT)**

Let us start where you have stopped: if you make the substitution $t = \sinh(x)$, it yields that

\begin{align*}
\int\frac{3t^{2}}{\sqrt{1 + t^{2}}}\mathrm{d}t & = 3\int\sinh^{2}(x)\mathrm{d}x = 3\int\frac{\cosh(2x) - 1}{2}\mathrm{d}x
\end{align*}

since $\cosh^{2}(x) - \sinh^{2}(x) = 1$, $(\sinh(x))' = \cosh(x)$ and $\cosh(2x) = 2\sinh^{2}(x) + 1$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: that's fundamentally what I did.

Comment: @Matheman I have edited my answer in order to provide a further result. You can tell me if you find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

The trigonometric route is to substitute $x = \sqrt{3}\tan\theta$, $dx = \sqrt{3} \sec^2\theta\,d\theta$. Then $\sqrt{3 + x^2} = \sqrt{3} \sec\theta$ and we get
$$\begin{aligned}
    \int_0^1 \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{3+x^2}}\,dx 
    &= \int_0^{\pi/6} \frac{3\tan^2\theta \sqrt{3}\sec^2\theta}{\sqrt{3} \sec\theta}\,d\theta
\\  &= \int_0^{\pi/6} 3\sec\theta\tan^2\theta\,d\theta
\end{aligned}$$
At this point you can either:

- Integrate by parts with $u=\tan\theta$ and $dv = \sec\theta\tan\theta\,d\theta$. The new integral is a multiple of $\sec^3\theta$.
- Substitute $\tan^2\theta = \sec^2\theta-1$ so the integrand is a multiple of $\sec^3\theta - \sec\theta$

Both $\int \sec\theta\,d\theta$ and $\int\sec^3\theta\,d\theta$ are “standard” memorizable (or lookupable) functions. We get

$$\begin{aligned}
     3\int_0^{\pi/6} \left(\sec^3\theta-\sec\theta\right)\,d\theta
    &= 3\left[\frac{1}{2}\sec\theta\tan\theta - \ln\left|\sec\theta+\tan\theta\right|\right]^{\pi/6}_0
    \\&= \frac{3}{2} \left(\sec\frac{\pi}{6}\tan\frac{\pi}{6} - \ln \left( \sec\frac{\pi}{6}+\tan\frac{\pi}{6}\right)\right)
    \\&= \frac{3}{2} \left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} - \ln \left( \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)\right)
    \\&= 1 - \frac{3}{4} \ln 3
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: It looks interesting. I'll try to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Following through with the suggested Euler substitution, let

$$u = \frac{\sqrt{t^2+1}-1}t \implies t = \frac{2u}{1-u^2} \implies dt = 2\frac{1+u^2}{(1-u^2)^2}\,du$$

Hence

$$\int_0^1 \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{3+x^2}} \, dx \stackrel{x=\sqrt3\,t}= \int_0^{\tfrac1{\sqrt3}} \frac{3t^2}{\sqrt{1+t^2}} \, dt \stackrel{t=\tfrac{2u}{1-u^2}}= 24 \int_0^{2-\sqrt3} \frac{u^2}{(1-u^2)^3}\, du$$

and you can break up the integrand into partial fractions to proceed.